# How to make service is global in library Angular?

Tags: angular, angular8

I have separated library in Angular project. This library has service `MapLibraryService`.

```
import { ReonMapApi } from "./map-api";

export class MapLibraryService {
  private readonly mapConfig = { key: "k123456_78" };

}
```

It was registed in module of library:

```
@NgModule({
  declarations: [MapLibraryComponent, MenuToolsComponent],
  imports: [],
  exports: [MapLibraryComponent],
  providers: nMapLibraryService]
})
export class MapLibraryModule {}
```

When in another part application I try to get instance of this service:

```
export class MapControlsComponent implements OnInit {
  constructor(private reonMapLibraryService: MapLibraryService) {
}
```

It returns me another instance of MapLibraryService

Comment: I think you'll have to import the library module in `AppModule`. But, in order to make its services globally available, you have 2 options: Either use `@Injectable({ providedIn: 'root' })` or you can use `MapLibraryModule.forRoot()`. More on the second approach [here](https://www.bennadel.com/blog/3565-providing-module-configuration-using-forroot-and-ahead-of-time-compiling-in-angular-7-2-0.htm).

Comment: Which version of angular are you using?

Comment: I would like to look at reproduction because as for me they should get the same instance

Comment: You must have imported `MapLibraryModule` in your application, right?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should decorate your service class with [@Injectable](https://angular.io/api/core/Injectable)

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class MapLibraryService {
  private readonly mapConfig = { key: "k123456_78" };

}
```

Comment: But in this case service will be singltone in library not in whole project. but I need to get instance of this library in another project inside Angular

Answer (score 3):

If you are using angular 9 release candidate version you can use platform injector,
Which will provide special singleton shared by all applications on the page.

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'platform'
})
```

[For More Info](https://dev.to/christiankohler/improved-dependeny-injection-with-the-new-providedin-scopes-any-and-platform-30bb)

Comment: Where platform it is project name?

Comment: No it is a injector same like root

Comment: Did you getwhat I need, I need share service from library Angular to another part of application in component

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204829/discussion-between-chellappan--and-opv).

Answer (score 2):

If I understand you correctly, you need to decorate your service with

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})
```

[Read more about singletons here](https://angular.io/guide/singleton-services)

Also check answer about  providedIn: 'platform', but it depends on angular version of your app.

Comment: But in this case service will be singltone in library not in whole project. but I need to get instance of this library in another project inside Angular

Comment: This tells Angular to provide the service in the application root. So it will be available in the whole app, where it was declared.

Comment: I have tried, it works only in library scope, not outside

Comment: Try providedIn: 'platform', if you're using angular 9

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to make a service global in angular.

1) Add a line in your service

```
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root',
})

export class MapLibraryService {
  private readonly mapConfig = { key: "k123456_78" };

}
```

**OR**

2) register service in `app.module.ts`:

```
providers: [MapLibraryService]
```

Comment: You dont understand I need global service among two projects libs in Angular

Comment: can you please tell me more information about this. I don't understand your requirements.